# Scala - the `apply()` without arguments method and curved braces on a call

Tags: scala, dsl

I am building a DSL with Scala and I have such an object:

```
object block {
  def apply(content: String): String = "{\n" + content + "}\n"
  def apply(): String = block("empty block")
}
```

so that later in my DSL I can say:

```
block {
  "good stuff goes here"
}
```

that's ok, but there is the second `apply()` method which I want to use to allow the user to write empty blocks, so to fill them later. But the compiler does not allow to call the no-arguments `apply()` method with curly braces... is there any way around that except using parentheses instead? If no, then why isn't this allowed?

**UPDATE:** For reference: the two answers should be combined for the full picture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of an apply method without any parameters, you can let it take a parameter of type `Unit` that is ignored:

```
def apply(ignored: Unit) = "{\n}\n"
```

Then you can write

```
block {}
```

Comment: @PrinceJohnWesley: Yes, changed that.

Answer (score 0):

**FINALLY**

```
object block { 
  def apply[T](content: => T) = "{\n" + 
    (content match { 
      case s: String => s
      case u: Unit => ""
      case a => a.toString 
    }) + "}\n" 
}
```

**EDIT**

To make a `block {}` working:

```
object block { def apply(content: => Unit) = "{\n" + content + "}\n" }
```

I insist on using a by-name parameter, not just a `Unit` as in another answer. Because `=> Unit` does actually create a function that can be executed by a `block.apply()` method, and `content: Unit` just takes as a parameter a block of code that will be executed in-place (before `block.apply()`).

Let's suppose that `block.apply` will print "Hoho". Now:

```
// content: Unit
block { println("Haha") }
// Haha
// Hoho

// content: => Unit
block { println("Haha") }
// Hoho
// Haha
```

**...**

Use by-name parameter:

```
object block { def apply(content: => String) = "{\n" + content + "}\n" }
```

Comment: -1 because this doesn't actually work: `block {}` is still a syntax error.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.  The OP wants `block {}` to work also.

Comment: Doh, I'd redeem you, man, so I upvote the answer, but my voice is yet lonely ) The difference on the moment of execution in both the cases, as you say, is an important thing to keep in mind!

Comment: Just un-accept a previous answer, and accept mine. A greed tick must appear =) Im sure Kim Stebel will not comply - he is a >10k man

Comment: Now a working but buggy answer--unit `()` is printed in the output, which is a weird choice.  Removed my -1, but not good enough for +1 IMO.